# Firefox service worker registration 'updatefound' event not triggered

Tags: firefox, service-worker

I cannot make 'updatefound' event trigger on Firefox 52.0.1. Everything works ok with Chrome.
The event should be triggered whenever service worker script changes. Here's the code. Nothing special there:

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
      .then(function(reg) {
        if (reg.waiting) {
          console.log('waiting');
          return;
        }

        if (reg.installing) {
          console.log('installing');
          return;
        }

        reg.addEventListener('updatefound', function() {
          console.log('service worker changed');
        });
      });
```

I got 'service worker changed' each time i change service-worker.js on Chrome. Hovewer does not work at all on Firefox.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue - can get Chrome to update the service worker every time I make a change to it, but Firefox never does. I've set all the recommended caching in to force it to never cache on the network

Answer (score 0):

Try (depending on your webserver) setting the cache-control header to "max-age=-1".